# postgres how to get desired result

Tags: postgresql

```
select count(*), templates.id as template_id,
                templates.name,
                checklists.status
                from templates
                left join checklists on checklists.template_id = templates.id and checklists.organization_id = 134 and checklists.company_id = 193
                where templates.organization_id = 134
                and (start_date between '2015-01-01' and '2020-01-01') and checklists.is_archived ='False'
                group by templates.id, templates.name, checklists.status
```

it results

```
count  | template_id |    name         |     status     
-------+-------------+-----------------+----------------
    21 |         157 | asdsd           | awaiting_reply
     1 |         157 | asdsd           | completed
    36 |         157 | asdsd           | pending
```

note here count is total number of checklist having status given in result
i.e for template_id 157, count is 21 having status awaiting reply

I want result should be reflected as

```
count  | template_id |    name         |     complete count   |     total count     
-------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------------
    21 |         157 | asdsd           |           1          +       58
```

how to do it.

Comment: remove `checklist.status` from groupby and from list of field in select

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following updated version:

```
SELECT
    t.template_id,
    t.name,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.status = 'completed') AS "complete count",
    COUNT(*) AS "total count"
FROM templates t
LEFT JOIN checklists c
    ON c.template_id = t.id AND
       c.organization_id = 134 AND
       c.company_id = 193
WHERE
    t.organization_id = 134 AND
    start_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' AND
    c.is_archived = 'False'
GROUP BY
    t.template_id,
    t.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, based on your expected result, you want 3 counts :

- 1 for status = awaiting_reply (= 21 in your example 'count')
- 1 for status = completed (= 1 in your example 'complete count')
- 1 for total count (= 58 in your example 'total count')

I think you could achieve this with the following query :

```
select 
     templates.id as template_id,
     templates.name,
     SUM(checklists.status = 'awaiting_reply') AS 'count',
     SUM(checklists.status = 'completed') AS 'complete_count',
     COUNT(1) AS 'total_count'
from templates
left join checklists 
     on checklists.template_id = templates.id 
     and checklists.organization_id = 134 
     and checklists.company_id = 193
where templates.organization_id = 134
     and (start_date between '2015-01-01' and '2020-01-01') 
     and checklists.is_archived ='False'
group by templates.id, templates.name
```